# Looking for a high resolution timer

Tags: c++, linux, timer

In C++ for Linux, I am trying to do something every microsecond/nanosecond and am currently using the nanosleep function below. It works, however if the code loops millions of times, this becomes expensive. I'm looking for a high resolution timer that will allow for a very precise timing (the application is audio/video). Any ideas?

```
struct timespec req = {0};
req.tv_sec = 0;
req.tv_nsec = 1000000000L / value;

for(long i = 0; i < done; i++)
{
    printf("Hello world");            
    nanosleep(&req, (struct timespec *)NULL);
}
```

Comment: Anything wrong with `<chrono>`?

Comment: If your CPU has a 4 GHz clock, you have 4 clock cycles in a nanosecond.  You cannot do very much every nanosecond, even at that speed.

Comment: What kind of linux and processor are we talking about? For Non- realtime systems anything higher than ms accuracy is already quite ambitious. Microsecond (not to mention nanosecond) accuracy is something you wouldn't even strive for on most real time systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `C++11`

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

...

for (long i = 0; i < done; i++) {
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;            
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(1e9 / value));
}
```

Remember to compile with `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: I compared the two approaches, and they seem to have very similar computational expense (the system call takes a long time). Is this really the best that can be done, or is it possible to use a special timer straight from the kernel or something?

Comment: @Josh I think that this is the best that can be done from the user side.

Answer (score 1):

For audio/video typically you don't need nano/micro seconds precision timers, milliseconds is enough. The most common inter-packet interval in audio is 20ms. It is okey to use nanosleep for that purpose.

Moreover unless you use realtime OS you can't guarantee to get so good timings from the kernel.

Pitfall of using sleeps in realtime communications is: they don't keep appropriate frequency (50Hz for audio with 20ms interval). Because on each tick you add processing time to sleep interval. So sleep interval must be calculated based on previous tick timestamp and next expected tick timestamp.

You can implement short interval timer (10ms for example) with sleeps and process events that should occur between this timer alarms on timer alarms. If you do so you will optimise OS resource usage (minimising process/threads context switching).

Answer (score 0):

You can get microsecond resolution with getitimer(2):

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html

Comment: Note that POSIX marks [`setitimer()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setitimer.html) and
[`getitimer()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getitimer.html) as obsolescent, and says that the preferred replacement functions are
[`timer_settime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_settime.html) and
[`timer_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_gettime.html).  The `getitimer()` and `setitimer()` functions won't vanish immediately, but the writing is on the wall.

Comment: OTOH, Mac OS X 10.10.4 does not have either `timer_settime()` or `timer_gettime()`, but it does have `getitimer()` and `setitimer()`.  So the 'obsolescent' functions have availability on their side.  Similar comments apply to `gettimeofday()` and `clock_gettime()` — Mac OS X has the former but POSIX prefers the latter and has marked the former as obsolescent.